# tastypie mongoengine rest api for DynamicDocument

Tags: python, django, tastypie, mongoengine

I am trying to save dynamic document in mongo using testypie and mongoengine my code is like this:

```
class Test(DynamicDocument):
    pass

class TestResource(resources.MongoEngineResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = models.Test.objects.all()
        allowed_methods = ('get', 'post', 'put', 'delete')
        authorization = authorization.Authorization()
```

and i am trying to save this object using rest api

```
{
  "fname":"Shon",
  "lname":"Lil"
}
```

I am geting this document in mongo

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("50bdf1a0d6b9bb12db267be4"),
    "_types" : [
        "Test"
    ],
    "_cls" : "Test"
}
```

I need document like this

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("50be06fcd6b9bb14d07f8866"),
    "_types" : [
        "Test"
    ],
    "lname" : "Lil",
    "_cls" : "Test",
    "fname" : "Shon"
}
```

can anybody help me on this?